# Sharp package error while trying to run Payload CMS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to follow a tutorial that is building an e-commerce project based on Payload CMS template
I'm creating the payload project based on e-commerce project and then clone it to my github then clone it to my local machine and try to install the dependencies with :
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

```
PS C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\WEB DEV\e-commerce-cms> npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm WARN deprecated memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\FPCC\\Desktop\\WEB DEV\\e-commerce-cms\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\WEB DEV\e-commerce-cms\node_modules\@aws-crypto'] {     
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\FPCC\\Desktop\\WEB DEV\\e-commerce-cms\\node_modules\\@aws-crypto'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\WEB DEV\e-commerce-cms\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.14.5/libvips-8.14.5-win32-x64.tar.br
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: Request timed out

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\FPCC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-08T17_17_02_626Z-debug-0.log
```

## **What I Tried :**

- installing **sharp** package on an independent project and it was installed successfully without any problems
- using other versions of node using NVM (16, 18 , 21, latest)
- removing sharp package from the package.json file of the project then tried to install it after installing package.json packages
- same step as above one but installing it using
  `npm install --platform=win32 --arch=x64 sharp`
- installing deps using yarn